# Get all image src from clicked li element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I get all `src` attributes of `img` elements in the clicked `li` element?

```
<ul id="container">
  <li>
    <br>
    <img src="src1"  />
    <img src="src2" style="display:none;" /> 
  </li>
```

```js
$('#container li').bind("click", function(e) {

});
```

Comment: `bind()` is very outdated. Use [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on) instead. To solve your actual issue, use [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map) to build an array of the `src` values.

Answer (score 2):

Using [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/), [.map](http://api.jquery.com/map/) and .get

It is not recommended to use the deprecated `.bind`

This code will react to a click on anything in the LI. It can be modified to only react to a click on an image in the LI

Use `return $(this).prop("src")` or `return this.src` if you want the fully qualified URL instead of just the string in the src="..."

```js
$('#container li').on("click", function(e) {
  const sources = $("img",this).map(function() { return $(this).attr("src") }).get()
  console.log(sources)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="container">
  <li><br><img src="src1" /><img src="src2" style="display:none;" /> </li>
  <li><br><img src="src3" /><img src="src4" style="display:none;" /> </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use $(this) within the event to get a hold of the clicked object. Then just search for the tags you are looking for.

```
$('#container li').bind("click", function(e) {
    var sources = $(this).find("img").map(function() { 
        return this.src; 
    }).get();         
});
```

Comment: Don't forget the `get()`, as in @mplungjan's answer

Comment: Make a snippet and test your code. It does not work - too many brackets

Comment: @mplungjan You are right. There was a console.log in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for this:

```js
$("#container").on("click", "li", function(e) {
  var links = [];
  $(this).find("img").each(function() {
    links.push($(this).attr("src"));
  });
  console.log(links);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="container">
  <li>
    <br>
    <img src="src1" />
    <img src="src2" style="display:none;" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <br>
    <img src="src3" />
    <img src="src4" style="display:none;" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Downvote isn't mine, but the OP wants to click the li and get all the img srcs

Comment: Which is what this will do :)

Comment: No, it will get the first one only.

Comment: It will fetch all the src from any img tags nested inside of the clicked li, which from my understanding is what was asked.

Comment: Your understanding of what's being asked is correct, but that's not what this does. It will get the `src` of the first `img` tag found in the collection. I'd suggest you create a jsFiddle and test it yourself if you don't believe me

Comment: I made you a snippet. See what it does.

Comment: Apologies, looks like you were right @RoryMcCrossan. Answer has now been amended to do what was requested. Thanks for pointing that out :)

Comment: No problem, although note that the logic is still broken as you are attempting to concatenate a string to an array. Try using the `push()` method instead (or `map()`, as per other answers)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following with `map()` and `get()`:

```js
$('#container li').on('click', function(){
  var srcList =  $(this).find('img').map( (i,s) => $(s).attr('src')).get();
  console.log(srcList);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="container">
  <li><br><img src="src1"  /><img src="src2" style="display:none;" /> </li>
  <li><br><img src="src3"  /><img src="src4" style="display:none;" /> </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter the container for images and add `src` into an array using `.push()` you can declare `img[]` array inside or outside the click function depending on the requirements

```js
$("#container li").on('click', function() {
  let img = [];
  $(this).find("img").each(function() {
    img.push($(this).attr('src'));
  });

  console.log(img);
});
```

```css
ul {
  background-color: blue;
}

li {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="container">
  <li>
    <br>
    <img src="src1.jpg" />
    <img src="src2.jpg" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <br>
    <img src="src3.jpg" />
    <img src="src4.jpg" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <br>
    <img src="src5.jpg" />
    <img src="src6.jpg" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: yeah filter was excessive and added as i was applying click on the container initially and not the `li` @mplungjan

Comment: the `https://stacksnippets.net/src1` is show by default as the source is provided as a name only `src1` if you provide a valid full URL like `http://example.com/image.jpg` it won't add the base URL , this happens for your answer too @mplungjan

Comment: It was not a criticism, just an observation

Comment: nah its ok i didnt mind that @mplungjan i love to learn :) you can point out mistakes if there are i never mind to learn